# Button flickering after fade in

Tags: css, wordpress, safari, webkit

Well documented question on the internet, but I seem to be able to find a solution that works and think I may be putting the code in the wrong place!

On safari, when a button or other element fades in, once it is faded in it then briefly flickers/flashes white - almost like it refreshes very quickly.

I've seen multiple suggestions online to use

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

or similar however have had no luck. I'm using a Divi Theme with Wordpress and was hoping someone could provide pointers as to how to solve this issue? It may be just that I'm putting the code into the wrong area!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try playing with the opacity of the button instead of the visibility like this

```css
button{
width:300px;
height:100px;
animation: 2s linear;
animation-name:bring-in;
}
@keyframes bring-in{
0%{opacity:0;}
100%{opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<button><h2>I am groot</h2></button>
```